# How do you defend against BladeMaster harrass/rush, early game?

Tags: warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne

For any of the 4 races, how do you place your buildings/what hero do you get/what do you build first to effectively protect yourself against that all-annoying BladeMaster rush with WindWalk, early game?

I'm talking *no* peon losses, ideally causing him to have to TP.

Comment: No, one start per race should not happen.  A correct answer should have 4 strats in it, not one race per answer.

Comment: Since i havent played Wc3 for a little bit, this is where i stand. What i dont have: specific BOs for each race including suggested heroes/counters. What i do have: General tips as well as what options each race has. Do you want an answer in this manner? and maybe we should consider this to be a CW?

Comment: By the text of your question, I am guessing that you know from the very beginning that you expect to be facing this strategy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't played in a long time so bare with me:

**Night Elf:**

```
Mana Burn (Demon Hunter)
Dust+Entangling Roots+Surround/Focus Fire (KotG)
Shadow Strike will slow allowing you to attack him with units(Warden)
Build your wells in a manner that blocks your trees so melee heroes cant get in
```

Alternatively, put lumber Wisps in random places around the map instead of at all
at your main (risky)

**Rec: DH**

**Human:**

```
Arcane Towers covering all peasants (Drains Mana)
Storm Bolt (MK)+Surround (Miltia, Footmen, Buildings)
^^His WW can run through but he won't come back out if he is weak^^
Use Water Elementals+AM Range to attack with Miltia as melee (AM)
Paladin can heal workers while they attack him
```

**Rec: MK**

**Undead:**

```
Nerubian Tower to slow (allows for easier chase damage)
Use Death Knight to heal Acolytes or nuke BM if you see a kill coming
Dreadlord can sleep/surround
Lich can slow as well
```

**Rec: DK**

Also, kite Acolytes around mine, Switching Acos location when he switchs target, Bring in Ghouls to surround/attack while DK heals Kiting Acos.

**Orc:**

```
Throw a few peons into burrow, definitely the ones he attacks
Build your initial Burrows so that they can cover your lumber and gold peons  
Attack with wolves + range (FS)
Throw up wards or hex/surround (SH)
Stun/attack (TC)
```

If you go BM you can just attack him as well for solid damage.

**Rec: Whichever hero you are most comfortable with**

In general, Kiting (running around/away) the peons he attacks will help prolong there life and inflict more damage to the BM for each worker kill.
This is just good all around and should become second habit early game.

Also, Another very strong approach is to counter-harass. Using natural base defenses (Towers, Wells to heal, miltia etc) as well as kiting, fend him off the
best you can while harassing his base (hopefully more succesfully) with your hero.This will force him to retreat or put you at a significant advantage exp and resource wise.
This is micro-intensive and should only be attempted if you are confident. Failing to succeed will put you at a significant disadvantage.

Comment: How are mana burn and owl related?

Comment: lmfao what a fail, too much footmen frenzy back in the day i guess. Thanks so much, Edited.

Comment: Oh yeah, potm owl would let you see him

Answer (score 2):

Haven't played War3 in a bit, but here's some suggestions.

- Human: Use a Mountain King. Bolt him as soon as he shows up, call the militia and surround him. This will probably make him retreat.
- Undead: I suggest a Death Night, since you can use coil both to heal your workers and nuke him. Just try to surround him with the hero and the ghouls and hit him as much as possible. Upgrading a Ziggurat to a Nerubian Tower helps too.
- Orc: Put your peons in the burrows and he won't have much to kill. All heroes can put a good fight against him, but I prefer a Far Seer with wolves or another Blademaster.
- Elves: Hardest race to deal with this kind of harassment. Use a Demon Hunter with Mana Burn, or a Warden with Shadow Strike. Don't keep your workers close together, and try to put them near wells so they can heal. If you're going to lose a worker, try to detonate and remove some of the enemy's mana.

In all cases, micromanaging workers to get them away from the Blademaster is important, as is micromanaging the units attacking the Blademaster.

Answer (score 0):

Hero Rushing is a standard part of Warcraft III. To Hero Rush means to attack the enemy town, especially workers, as early as possible. Players head to the enemy town as soon as the Hero has been trained. Players are typically either Hero Rushing the enemy or defending against a Hero Rush. Sometimes players may not Hero rush or may decide to Creep instead but Hero Rushing is found in most ladder games.

Reasons for Hero Rushing include:

- Distraction
  People who advance quickly up the tech-tree don't have a strong army. They need to distract and "harass" you until they are able to build their high end units. This involves doing regular hit-and-run attacks on your town. Usually if people are Hero Rushing you and they don't bring units with them, they are teching. You know it's time to go hit their base before they get whatever they are trying to build.
- Fun
  Hero rushing is fun! It's fun to attack players who don't know how to handle a Hero Rush. If the enemy is really bad at the game you can totally hose them and win the whole game. In Warcraft II and StarCraft there was a "build up" time where there wasn't a lot going on. Many players found this phase of the game boring. The answer was Heroes very early so that players have something fun to do at the beginning of the game.

**Good Hero Rushers**

- Demon Hunter (Mana Burn/Immolation)
- Blademaster (Wind Walk)
- Warden (Shadow Strike/Fan of Knives)
- Keeper of the Grove (Entangling Roots)
- Far Seer (dogs)
- Shadow Hunter (Serpent Wards)
- Archmage (Blizzard the workers/Water Elementals)
- Mountain King (Storm Bolt - good in 2 vs. 2 games)
- Naga Sea Witch (Forked Lightning/Frost Arrow)
- Crypt Lord (Beetles/Impale with Ghouls)

OK Hero Rushers
Some of these might be more effective in Team Games with help.

- Blood Mage (Flame Strike)
- Death Knight (Death Coil to Heal + Ghouls)
- Tauren Chieftain (Stomp/Shockwave)
- Beastmaster
- Pandaren Brewmaster (Drunken Haze)
- Dread Lord (Sleep/Carrion Swarm with Ghouls)
- Lich (Frost Nova)
- Dark Ranger (possible if you go Life Drain first).

Semi-Bad Hero Rushers

- Priestess of the Moon (at least go Searing Arrow first and come with an ally)
- Pit Lord (gets stuck).

They are ok if they are supporting another Hero and are not being hit.

Extremely Bad Hero Rushers

- Paladin (laugh whenever you see this)

**Anti Hero Rushers**
The same Heroes that are good for Hero Rushing are also good at defending against Hero rushes typically. Some of the best anti Hero Rushers are:

- Demon Hunter (Mana Burn)
- Mountain King (Storm Bolt)
- Warden (Shadow Strike)
- Far Seer (dogs/Chain Lightning)

**Defense against Hero Rushes**

All:
Lead the enemy away until you can build up enough forces to take them on. Hit, then run away from your town. Use your Town's defenses!

Humans:
Get an Arcane Tower! Use Militia if they get close but go back to work if they run away.

Orcs:
Hop in those Burrows. Build 1-2 Watch Towers

Undead:
Run the Acolytes away. Build 1 Nerubian Tower. Use a Death Knight to heal the Acolytes

Night Elves:  Use Detonate. Fight by the Moon Wells. Build your town in such a way that the Ancients of War can defend you.

Comment: Looks like a copy paste of the [WC3 website](http://classic.battle.net/war3/basics/herorushing.shtml)...